# Got NoClassDefFoundError when passing map of lambda

Tags: java, lambda, kotlin

I create an Android app by using Kotlin, and there's something strange with lambda. I pass `mapOf(1 to {...}, 2 to {...})` and get `NoClassDefFoundError` or `ClassNotFoundException`.

I try to rewrite it in desktop, and get the same, but with different stack trace.

```
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        call(mapOf(
            1 to { "asd" },
            2 to { 999 }
        ))
    }

    fun call(x: Map<Int, () -> Any>) {

    }
```

This is the stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics
    at TestKt.main(test.kt)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.runner.AbstractRunner.run(runners.kt:61)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.runner.Main.run(Main.kt:109)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.runner.Main.main(Main.kt:119)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 8 more
```

Comment: How are you running this?  Through IntelliJ?

Comment: @GregKopff Originally it's in Android, this version is I reproduce in desktop.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a problem in your code. It is a problem with running your application. 
Kotlin comes with its own standard class library `kotlin-runtime.jar`. You should have this library in classpath:

```
java -cp $KOTLIN_HOME/lib/kotlin-runtime.jar:MyApp.jar com.my.AppKt
```

or your should compile the application with `-include-runtime`:

```
kotlinc app.kt -include-runtime -d MyApp.jar
```

Comment: No, I run it with `kotlin test.jar TestKt`

Comment: In this case you should compile the application with `-include-runtime`:

`kotlinc test.kt -include-runtime -d test.jar`

Comment: Actually the problem I face is in Android. I tried it in desktop just for test.